# How can use JSON Autocomplete on php subpages new

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, include

I have a question regarding autocomplete of an Input field.
I have a main Page which includes a 2nd page

quallabtools_home.php?page=fertigung/add_new_tool.php

**Current Code within the Main Page quallabtools_home.php
to include 2nd Page:**

```
*$page = stripslashes($_GET["page"]);<br>
include ($page);*
```

I want to use json Ajax Autocomplete on the included Page fertigung/add_new_tool.php.

**Current Code within the Included Page add_new_tool.php
to get autocomplete:**

```
<head>
    <title>Bootstrap Autocomplete with Dynamic Data Load using PHP Ajax</title>
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="typeahead.js"></script>
        
</head>
<body>
    
         <input type="text" name="txtCountry" id="txtCountry" class="typeahead"/>
    
</body>
    *<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#txtCountry').typeahead({
                source: function (query, result) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "server.php",
                        data: 'query=' + query,            
                        dataType: "json",
                        type: "POST",
                        success: function (data) {
                            result($.map(data, function (item) {
                                return item;
                            }));
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    </script>*
```

Server.php is holding the MYSQL Database Query which is working fine.
Is their any way to do this.

I got it working on the Page (add_new_tool.php ) itself, but when i open the Main Page with the include of the Subpage (quallabtools_home.php?page=fertigung/add_new_tool.php) it won't work anymore.

Big Thanks in advance and Best Regards

Comment: Please don't do this! Your code is _highly_ insecure since you've given your _users_ the power to include whatever file they want on your system that your PHP user has access to!

Comment: Is there any Suggestion how to do the include of the different subpages on the Main Page, with the running the ajax within the subpage. I've already readed something about jquery .load. But how can i handle the changing page variable?? I'm happy about every answer. Big thanks.

Comment: The main point of my comment wasn't that you shouldn't do something similar to what you're doing though. It's just that you should _never ever_ trust anything you get from the frontend. You should always validate the data before using it. You could, for example, do `somepage.php?page=foobar`. Then in PHP, you have a list of valid pages: `$pages = ['foobar' => 'the-actual-file.php', 'batman' => 'some-other-file.php']`. Then check if what the user sends exists in the array. If yes, then get the real file path from the array and include that. If not, show a 404 page or something.

Comment: I'm not sure what the actual issue you're asking about is though. I don't see why the Ajax code wouldn't work just because you've included it using PHP. The browser (where the JS is being executed) has no idea if it was included using PHP or hardcoded. If `server.php` is in the root folder of your site (like: `example.com/server.php`), then try changing `url: "server.php",` to `url: "/server.php",`. Prefix it with `/` will make it load it from the root of the site. Without the slash, the browser will just add it to the current URL instead.

Comment: Thanks for your Input. I've found the Issue. It Was css class related which prevented the autocomplete. Thanks again for the Inputs